# Best practices for reusability in .net core web app

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017, components, asp.net-core-2.0, code-reuse

In older MVC4/5 applications we had the ability to create a partial view and share it on different web pages of the application. However, what we couldn't do in a practical matter was to put this view in a separate assembly (e.g. DLL) and share it in other web application projects.

Is it now possible using VS2017 and .Net Core to share components across projects?

For example, assume that there are multiple web sites which gather data from different groups of clients.  I want to build a shared component that gathers address info, then put that code into an assembly and then reference the assembly in each of the individual websites whether they are using Angular, Vue.js, React, or some other framework.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a component library. More information here: https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue of sharing artifacts as components between projects is not limited to DLL's

Long before the `ASP.NET MVC`, in `ASP.net WebForms`, we would create components in assemblies and shared them - (that is, `ServerControls`) as you would like.

In the case of `ASP.net MVC`, as you said, we had `PartialViews` that could be shared between application pages.

When there was a need to create a UI component or not, to share it with other projects, a common approach was to create `Custom HtmlHelpers`. But it was also possible to distribute PartialViews through nuget packages.

Nowadays, for the UI components of the JS frameworks, like the ones you mentioned in the example (angular and like), the assemblies will not work (assemblies are for server-side code).

So, after creating your front-end component, create `npm`, `bower` or `nuget packages` (I recommend npm because that's how front-end [not only] components are commonly distributed) that contain your components and install the package in the projects you want to use them.

By this way, you will reuse the code for your UI components and even be able to version them.